# Norm function is lsc in the weak topology

Tags: functional-analysis

So, I want to prove that the norm function is lsc in the weak topology, i.e, given $\epsilon > 0$, there exists a neighborhood $V$ of $x_0$ s.t $\forall x \in V$, $||x|| > ||x_0|| - \epsilon$. So, I'm having trouble in finding a good neighborhood. Furthermore, I think Hahn-Banach theorem must be applied in some way. Am I right? Could you gimme some advice? Thanks in advance

Comment: I don't know if Hahn-Banach _must_ be used, but it's the standard way. Do you know a connection between the norm of $x_0$ and linear functionals?

Comment: Actually no, Dani. I was trying something like that so I could use this functonal to define my neighborhood

Comment: Cause we know that sets like $V(f_1, \dots , f_n)$ are open right

Comment: So i tried for a while to find a relation to define this $V$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By the Hahn-Banach theorem, there is a continuous linear functional $\lambda$ with $\lVert\lambda\rVert = 1$ and $\lambda(x_0) = \lVert x_0\rVert$. With that, the desired neighbourhood of $x_0$ is easily constructed, for example $V = \{ x : \lambda(x) > \lVert x_0\rVert - \epsilon\}$ is such a neighbourhood. Or $\tilde{V} = \{ x : \lvert \lambda(x-x_0)\rvert < \epsilon\}$.

Comment: Yay, dude, Thanks. Just applied your tip and did it. haha Yeah, I forgot this (very important) consequence of HB. Thanks again, Dani :)